# How to consume `.env.local` in `package.json` script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, package.json

I have these files .env.* in `/src` folder:

- .env
- .env.local
- .env.staging

`src/.env`:
REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=123

`src/.env.local`:
REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=456.

So i installed `env-cmd` package, and in the `package.json` i've added that script:

`"build:local":"env-cmd .env.local direflow-scripts build"`

On executing it: `yarn build:local`,
i get **error**:

````
```
   $ env-cmd .env.local direflow-scripts build
   spawn .env.local ENOENT
   error Command failed with signal "SIGINT".```
````

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the file `-f, --file` flag which would allow you to consume custom `.env` files.

Instead of `env-cmd .env.local direflow-scripts build`, just as the ["Help" section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd#-help) suggests, you should try:

```
$ env-cmd -f .env.local direflow-scripts build
```